# What happens to Darwin allocated getline buffers?

Tags: c, swift, swift2, darwin

Suppose I call [getline](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/getline.3.html) in swift with something like this:

```
import Darwin

let byLine = { (file : UnsafeMutablePointer<FILE>) in
    anyGenerator({ () -> String? in
        var input = UnsafeMutablePointer<Int8>()
        var lim = 0
        return getline(&input, &lim, file) > 0 ? String.fromCString(input) : nil
    })
}
```

Note this specific documentation for `ssize_t getline(char **lineptr, size_t *n, FILE *stream);`:

> If *lineptr is set to NULL and *n is set 0 before the call, then
>          getline() will allocate a buffer for storing the line.  This buffer
>          should be freed by the user program even if getline() failed.

Now suppose I have:

```
let fd = fopen("a_billion_lines_of_text.txt", "r")
for line in byLine(fd) {
    ...
}
```

What happens to the billion lines of text as the `for` loop reads that file line by line?

This code does work for reading a file line by line, but what happens to each line buffer allocated by `getline`? Does swift free it or is it a memory leak?

Comment: Given that you’re not freeing what the documentation explicitly says you need to free, it’s a memory leak.

Comment: How do you free that in swift? I know how to do that in C, but not indirectly in swift.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The buffers are leaked. You need to free the memory after calling `getline`. Here's how you can do that.

```
let byLine = { (file : UnsafeMutablePointer<FILE>) in
    anyGenerator({ () -> String? in
        var input = UnsafeMutablePointer<Int8>()
        var lim = 0
        let numChars = getline(&input, &lim, file)
        defer {
            free(input)
        }            
        return numChars > 0 ? String.fromCString(input) : nil
    })
}
```

Comment: Would `defer` execute at the closing scope and free `input` before it is used?

Comment: `input` will not be freed before it is used. The code in the `defer` block will execute just prior to returning, but after all other code in the closure is done executing. That means the free will happen after `numChars > 0 ? String.fromCString(input) : nil)` has been evaluated.

Comment: Then the function (closure) is copying the contents of `input` to a different buffer prior to freeing it? In C, calling `free` on a buffer that you then return from a function is a common mistake...

Comment: The method `String.fromCString(_:)` copies the data from the buffer (see [the documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios//documentation/Swift/Reference/Swift_String_Structure/index.html#//apple_ref/swift/structcm/String/s:ZFSS11fromCStringFMSSFGVSs13UnsafePointerVSs4Int8_GSqSS_)). So you are not returning the buffer itself, but either nil or a new String created by copying the character data from the buffer.